# Automated featured product woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-featured-image

This is my first post in this great community. Normally I find all the answers to my small and large problems, but this I'am sad to say is a mystery to me :(

I need to create some kind of automated function that every day, once a day chooses 3 random products and marks them as featured in my Woocommerce store. And the next day removes these 3 and chooses 3 new once.

Sadly due to complicity of the task(for my), I have no code to show/start from.

Only thing I can find is that it has to be defined in some meta information:

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'product',  
    'meta_key' => '_featured',  
    'meta_value' => 'yes',
)
```

Truely hope someone can help me :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Making the function automated? Or the algorithm to find 3 random but new items?

Comment: @Marc, a bit of both sadly. I guess thee "setting 3 random new products" is the major problem, the timing setting shold perhaps not be that difficult? :)

Comment: How about a new column `last_time_featured` in your product table. Each time you feature it, set the timestamp to `now`. Then on the next day, select  3 items with the lowest `last_time_featured` timestamp (no timestamp aka not yet featured should be the lowest). This is very abstract, since I don't know anything about woocommerce.

Comment: Looks like you need a cron job to run a script to randomise the posts... How about looking into that? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112767/scheduling-posts-to-update-once-per-day-with-wp-cron

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to use [transients](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

Here's a suggestion, but first a couple of caveats.

1. if no one visits your site the transients don't always clear at the right times, but if that's an issue you can set up a ping service to automatically hit your site every day.
2. you don't have precise control over when the transient clears... ex: every day at 3pm.
3. This suggestion requires you to rework how your theme is displaying these 3 featured products. since we aren't actually looking for the `_featured` meta.

code for `functions.php`:

```
function so_35312355_get_daily_featured_products(){

    // Get any existing copy of our transient data
    if ( false === ( $daily_featured_products = get_transient( 'daily_featured_products' ) ) ) {
        // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'orderby'        => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => '3',

        );

        $daily_featured_products = new WP_Query( $args );

        set_transient( 'daily_featured_products', $daily_featured_products, 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    }

    return $daily_featured_products;

}
```

Alternatively, you could run 2 queries.... one to reset all the featured meta keys and a second to update the meta keys for each of your random 3 products.

A more advanced and *complete* method would be to use cron jobs. Take a look in the Codex for how to [schedule an event](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event), but depending on your needs the transient *may* be enough.